# Better multithreading with network IO and database queries

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, curl

I'm writing a script that:

1. fetch a list of urls from a db (about 10000 urls)
2. download all the pages and insert them into the db
3. parse the code
4. if(some condition) do other inserts into the db

I have a Xeon quad-core with hyper-threading, so a total of 8 thread available and I'm under Linux (64 bit).

I'm using `cStringIO` as buffer, `pycurl` to fetch the pages, `BeautifulSoup` to parse them and `MySQLdb` to interact with the database.

I tried to simplify the code below (removing all the try/except, parsing operation, ...).

```
import cStringIO, threading, MySQLdb.cursors, pycurl

NUM_THREADS = 100
lock_list = threading.Lock()
lock_query = threading.Lock()


db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "...", user = "...", passwd = "...", db = "...", cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT...")
rows = cur.fetchall()
rows = [x for x in rows]  # convert to a list so it's editable


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        """ initialize a StringIO object and a pycurl object """

        while True:
            lock_list.acquire()  # acquire the lock to extract a url
            if not rows:  # list is empty, no more url to process
                lock_list.release()
                break
            row = rows.pop()
            lock_list.release()

            """ download the page with pycurl and do some check """

            """ WARNING: possible bottleneck if all the pycurl
                connections are waiting for the timeout """

            lock_query.acquire()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO ...")  # insert the full page into the database
            db.commit()
            lock_query.release()

            """do some parse with BeautifulSoup using the StringIO object"""

            if something is not None:
                lock_query.acquire()
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO ...")  # insert the result of parsing into the database
                db.commit()
                lock_query.release()


# create and start all the threads
threads = []
for i in range(NUM_THREADS):
    t = MyThread()
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

# wait for threads to finish
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

I use `multithreading` so I don't need to wait if some requests are going to fail for timeout. That specific thread will wait but the others are free to continue with the other urls.

Here is a screenshot while doing nothing but the script:

[image]
It seems that 5 cores are busy while the other are not. So the questions are:

- should I create as many cursors as the number of threads?
- do I really need to lock the execution of a query? What happened if a thread execute a *cur.execute()* but not the *db.commit()* and another thread come in doing the *execution + commit* with another query?
- I read about the [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) class, but I'm not sure if I understood correctly: can I use it instead of doing *lock + extract a url + release*?
- using `multithreading` can I suffer from I/O (network) bottleneck? With 100 threads my speed doesn't exceed ~500Kb/s while my connection can go faster. If I move to `multiprocess` will I see some improvement on this side?
- the same question but with MySQL: using my code, there could be a bottleneck on this side? All those *lock + insert query + release* can be improved in some way?
- if the way to go is `multithreading`, is 100 an high number of threads? I mean, too many threads doing I/O requests (or DB queries) are useless because of the mutual exclusion of these operations? Or more threads means more network speed?

  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi707.png):

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [eventlet](http://eventlet.net) library. It'll let you write code that fetches all the web pages in parallel without ever explicitly implementing threads or locking.

```
import cStringIO, threading, MySQLdb.cursors, pycurl

NUM_THREADS = 100
lock_list = threading.Lock()
lock_query = threading.Lock()
```

The purist that I am, I wouldn't make this locks globals.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "...", user = "...", passwd = "...", db = "...", cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT...")
rows = cur.fetchall()
rows = [x for x in rows]  # convert to a list so it's editable
```

It would make more sense to do this sort of thing after you've define your classes. At least that would be python's convention.

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        """ initialize a StringIO object and a pycurl object """
```

that's pretty much the most terrible description of this function I could have come up with. (You seem to be thinking of that as a comment, but by convention this should be a docstring, and describe the function)

```
        while True:
            lock_list.acquire()  # acquire the lock to extract a url
            if not rows:  # list is empty, no more url to process
                lock_list.release()
                break
            row = rows.pop()
            lock_list.release()
```

It'd be a lot simpler to use a queue. It'd basically do all of that part for you.

```
            """ download the page with pycurl and do some check """

            """ WARNING: possible bottleneck if all the pycurl
                connections are waiting for the timeout """

            lock_query.acquire()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO ...")  # insert the full page into the database
            db.commit()
            lock_query.release()
```

It'd be better to put this data in another queue and have a database thread take care of it. This works, but I think the multi-queue approach would be cleaner.

```
            """do some parse with BeautifulSoup using the StringIO object"""

            if something is not None:
                lock_query.acquire()
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO ...")  # insert the result of parsing into the database
                db.commit()
                lock_query.release()
```

Same here. Note that there is no point in python of trying to split up processing using threads. The GIL means you'll get no advatange.

```
# create and start all the threads
threads = []
for i in range(NUM_THREADS):
    t = MyThread()
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

# wait for threads to finish
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: *should I create as many cursors as the number of threads?*

A: <del>Yes</del> Maybe. Don't share DB connection among threads, as docs say thread safety level = 1. Maybe better to have a `queue` of db connections. Once a thread popped a cursor from the queue, it's his only.

Q: *do I really need to lock the execution of a query?*

A: No. Trust your DB to take care for its own locking. That's what DBs are for.

Q: *I read about the Queue class...*

A: <del>You don't need any locks *at all* in this code. Just don't share anything.</del> Yap, a `queue` of db connections would be great here.

Q: *using multithreading can I suffer from I/O (network) bottleneck?*

A: Yes, but that's not a point against threads.

Q: *using my code, there could be a bottleneck...*

A: Though 'bottles necks' should be verified by testing, not by reading anonymous posts on forums, it's very likely that *downloading the files* will always be your bottle neck, regardless of implementation.

Q: *if the way to go is multithreading, is 100 an high number of threads?*

A: I don't think you should explicitly use threads *at all* here. Can't you assign a callback to an async http request?

---

Code sample for async http request, taken almost as-is from [this post](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/asyncore/):

I still owe you the db part.

```
import socket
import asyncore
from cStringIO import StringIO
from urlparse import urlparse

def noop(*args):
    pass

class HttpClient(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, url, callback = noop):
        self.url = url
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.write_buffer = 'GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' % self.url
        self.read_buffer = StringIO()
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect((urlparse(url).netloc, 80))
        self.on_close = callback

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        self.read_buffer.write(data)

    def handle_write(self):
        sent = self.send(self.write_buffer)
        self.write_buffer = self.write_buffer[sent:]

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()
        self.on_close(self.url, self.read_buffer.getvalue())

def parse(source, response):
    print source, 'got', len(response), 'bytes' 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clients = [HttpClient('http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18618/improve-multithreading-with-network-io-and-database-queries/18642#18642/', parse),
        HttpClient('http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/contents.html', parse)]

    print ('LOOP STARTING')
    asyncore.loop()
    print ('LOOP DONE')
```